# Execute more than one statement at once in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using MySQL Database. The following piece creates a record and gets the id from the created record:

```
    insertStmt = connection
                    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO bugs (summary, status, report_date) VALUES (?, ?, ? )");
            //...
    insertStmt.executeUpdate();
    idQuery = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
    rs = idQuery.executeQuery();
    if (rs != null) {
                rs.next();
                return new Long(rs.getLong(1)).toString();
    }
```

Now, if two threads execute this and their execution is interleaved, say, the first thread inserts the record followed by the insertion by the second thread, after which the first thread calls last_insert_id() which will be incorrect for this thread as the second thread has already inserted a record.
This might be overcome using synchronization, however. Is there a way we can execute the two statements in a single database call?

Comment: The two threads will need to use two different connections - which is required if you want to separate the transactions. And if they use different connections there is no problem.

Comment: even if there are different connections, insertion will be in same table, hence the chance of inconsistency.

Comment: No, you won't have any inconsistency, because the database will make sure you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID` works per-connection, and as your question states you can have a race condition if two statements in two threads use the same connection.

You have two ways around this:

1: Use a separate connection per thread (not easy, but this is really the best option for scaling and sense; use connection pooling)

2: Use the form of  `executeUpdate` that [records the auto-generated key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) in the same API call, allowing you to read it back later using `getGeneratedKeys` so that you don't have to use `LAST_INSERT_ID` in a second query, so avoiding the race condition. There's a similar form of [`prepareStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that you can use in prepared statements.

Option 2 is probably what you want in the short term. The link in option 2 goes straight to that API. [This link](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/autoincrement-with-connectorj.html) is a MySQL article outlining how to use it.

Comment: The executeUpdate() statement you linked to doesn't return the generated keys. It returns the row count or 0.

Comment: This was helpful. There is a restriction on using PreparedStatement with this method, which I actually want to use as they are faster and better.

Comment: You can use a similar technique with the `prepareStatement` call: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: You should really avoid sharing a single connection with multiple threads concurrently. Using a connection per thread is the correct way. Also AFAIK, the MySQL Connector/J driver actually executes a separate query with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` itself. So when multiple threads use the same connection there is still the possibility of a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html, you should be able to add `?allowMultiQueries=true` to your JDBC connection string. Then you would be able to pass multiple statements, separated by semicolons, in `Statement#execute(String sql)` calls.

Edit: or, use a stored procedure that does what you want. Or, as you said, `synchronize` the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Multiquery, combined the Insert and the Select Last_INSERT_ID() in the same string.

1) prepare the connection for using the multiquery: 
"jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+database+"?allowMultiQueries=true"

2) Combine The Insert Query with the Select:

multiQuerySqlString="INSERT INTO bugs (summary, status, report_date) VALUES (1, 2, 3 ); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"

3) esecute the query and expecting multiple result sets:

```
boolean isResultSet = statement.execute();

ResultSet res = statement.getResultSet();

if isResultSet = statement.getMoreResults();

// Second ReulstSet object
res = cs.getResultSet();
```

I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to do this all on a single connection you can ask the driver to return the generated ID:

```
insertStmt = connection.prepareStatement("...",PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );
insertStmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = insertStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
Long id = null;
if (rs != null) 
{
  rs.next();
  id = rs.getLong(1);
}
connection.commit();
return id;
```

Depending on the driver you might need a different `prepareStatement()` call that takes the column names as the second parameter:

```
insertStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT ", new String[] {"ID"});
```

But even in with the above code you should be doing the concurrent inserts on different physical connections to be able to properly control your transactions.